# csv: writer.writerows() splitting my string inputs

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of strings which I would like to write to a csv file. The list `list_results` looks like

```
['False, 60, 40 ', 'True, 70, 30, ']
```

So, I would try something like this:

```
with open('example1.csv', 'w') as result:
    writer = csv.writer(result, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow( ('Correct?', 'Successes', 'Failures') )
    writer.writerows(list_results)
```

Unfortunately, the data doesn't write into three columns. I find:

```
['Correct?', 'Successes', 'Failures']  
['F', 'a', 'l', 's', 'e', ',', ' ', '6', '0', ',', ' ', '4', '0', ' ']  
['T', 'r', 'u', 'e', ',', ' ', '7', '0', ',', ' ', '3', '0', ',', ' ']
```

How do I format this behavior appropriately to get

```
['Correct?', 'Successes', 'Failures']  
['False', 60, 40]  
['True', 70, 30]
```

Preferably in format `%s %d %d` ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are using `writer.writerows()` with an `s` at the end. That method expects a *list of lists*, but you passed in a list of strings. The `writerows()` method essentially does this:

```
def writerows(self, rows):
    for row in rows:
        self.writerow(row)
```

where each row must be a sequence of columns. A string is a sequence of individual characters, so that's what you get written: individual characters separated by your chosen delimiter.

You'll need to split out your string into columns, don't include the commas yourself, it's the job of the writer object to include those:

```
with open('example1.csv', 'w') as result:
    writer = csv.writer(result, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(('Correct?', 'Successes', 'Failures'))
    for row in list_results:
        columns = [c.strip() for c in row.strip(', ').split(',')]
        writer.writerow(columns)
```

or using a generator expression so you can keep using `writerows()`:

```
with open('example1.csv', 'w') as result:
    writer = csv.writer(result, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(('Correct?', 'Successes', 'Failures'))
    writer.writerows([c.strip() for c in r.strip(', ').split(',')]
                     for r in list_results)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> list_results = ['False, 60, 40 ', 'True, 70, 30, ']
>>> import csv
>>> import sys
>>> list_results = ['False, 60, 40 ', 'True, 70, 30, ']
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
>>> writer.writerow(('Correct?', 'Successes', 'Failures'))
Correct?,Successes,Failures
>>> for row in list_results:
...     columns = [c.strip() for c in row.strip(', ').split(',')]
...     writer.writerow(columns)
...
False,60,40
True,70,30
>>> writer.writerows([c.strip() for c in r.strip(', ').split(',')]
...                  for r in list_results)
False,60,40
True,70,30
```

Comment: I get an error for `columns = [c.strip() for c in result.split(',')]` which is `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: @ShanZhengYang: then your `list_results` does not contain just strings as you claim in your question.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang: the error means that *at least one* of your `list_result` elements is not a string but a list. Can you update your question with *all* of your data?

Comment: It appears so... `['False, 60, 40 ', 'True, 70, 30, ']` That's a list of two strings

Comment: @ShanZhengYang: with that list, the error you claim is thrown is not thrown.

Comment: I understand now. Hmmm. I'll look to see what the issue is. I was just calling the variable...

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your `list_results` contains something like:

```
['False, 60, 40 ', 'True, 70, 30, ']
```

`writerows()` takes a list of lists, you supply a list of strings, a string is iterable and is thus converted into list of chars, what you want is:

```
with open('example1.csv', 'w') as result:
    writer = csv.writer(result, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow( ('Correct?', 'Successes', 'Failures') )
    writer.writerows([c.strip() for c in r.split(',')] for r in list_results)
```

Comment: I think this is right, but I get an error. `list_results` is a list

    writer.writerows([c.strip() for c in r] for r in list_results.split(','))    
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Heh did not copy it, just made the same error. I've fixed my answer now

Answer (score 0):

it works fine:

`list_results = [(False, 60, 40), (True, 70, 30)]`

This is source code for `writer.writerows()` on C.

```
static PyObject *
csv_writerows(WriterObj *self, PyObject *seqseq)
{
    PyObject *row_iter, *row_obj, *result;
```

```
row_iter = PyObject_GetIter(seqseq);
if (row_iter == NULL) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
                    "writerows() argument must be iterable");
    return NULL;
}
while ((row_obj = PyIter_Next(row_iter))) {
    result = csv_writerow(self, row_obj);
    Py_DECREF(row_obj);
    if (!result) {
        Py_DECREF(row_iter);
        return NULL;
    }
    else
         Py_DECREF(result);
}
Py_DECREF(row_iter);
if (PyErr_Occurred())
    return NULL;
Py_INCREF(Py_None);
return Py_None;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

`writerows` expects a list of lists. So if you give a list to `writerows` it will convert it into list of list ( i.e. fragmenting words into letters.

```
import csv
list_results = ['False, 60, 40 ', 'True, 70, 30, ']

with open(r"C:\test.csv", 'wb') as result:
    writer = csv.writer(result, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow( ('Correct?', 'Successes', 'Failures') )
    writer.writerows([i.strip().split(',') for i in list_results])
```

Or if you want to use `writerow`-

```
import csv
list_results = ['False, 60, 40 ', 'True, 70, 30, ']

with open(r"C:\mnp_.csv", 'wb') as result:
    writer = csv.writer(result, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow( ('Correct?', 'Successes', 'Failures') )
    data = [i.strip().split(',') for i in list_results]
    for d in data:
        writer.writerow(d)
```

Output-

```
Correct?    Successes   Failures
FALSE   60  40
TRUE    70  30
```

Comment: That gives me 

    ['Correct?', 'Successes', 'Failures']
    ['False, 60, 40 ', 'True, 70, 30, ']

Comment: Can I somehow parse this string correctly to be in the correct columns?

Comment: @SIslam: that's **nonsense**. The OP doesn't have dictionaries to write here.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang: yes, you'll need to split out your strings into columns.