# Why when I save a list of string into csv file, characters are separated?

Tags: string, python-2.7, list, csv, export-to-csv

I have a list of animal name (dog, cat, cow) called animals. When I print it in python, animals name are printed correctly. But, when I save this list (animals) into CSV file, each name of animal save in separate mood. For example, if I have a list such as `a=["dog","cat","lion"]`, each of CSV file are "d,o,g" and "c,a,t" and "l,i,o,n".
This is my code:

```
animals=["dog","cat","lion"]
import csv
    with open('animal.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerows(animals)
```

Comment: I think you have the problem described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285154/csv-writer-writerows-splitting-my-string-inputs

Comment: It was very useful. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

It worked correctly:

```
animal=["dog","cat","lion"]
with open('animal1.csv', 'w') as result:
    writer = csv.writer(result, delimiter=",")

    writer.writerows([c.strip() for c in r.strip(', ').split(',')]
                     for r in animal)
```