# How to write values to CSV file in two columns using Python 3?

Tags: python, csv

How do I write two columns in my CSV file? The first should have data[0] and the second should have data[1]

```
with open('list_of_courses.csv', 'w', newline='', delimiter=',') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)

    for dept_courses in dept_url_dict.values():
        newpage = requests.get("https://bulletin.temple.edu"+dept_courses)
        courses = BeautifulSoup(newpage.content, 'html.parser')
        courselist = courses.select('p.courseblocktitle')
        print(dept_courses)
        for c in courselist:
            string = c.text
            data = string.split(".")
            thewriter.writerow(data[0]+","+data[1])
```

I want the CSV file to have two columns, but it currently has a column for each character.

Comment: You should pass a `list` to `writerow` function, instead of passing a string separated by `','`. Try `thewriter.writerow([data[0], data[1]])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [csv: writer.writerows() splitting my string inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285154/csv-writer-writerows-splitting-my-string-inputs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
with open('list_of_courses.csv', 'w', newline='', delimiter=',') as f:
   thewriter = csv.writer(f) 
   for dept_courses in dept_url_dict.values():    
       newpage=requests.get("https://bulletin.temple.edu"+dept_courses)
       courses = BeautifulSoup(newpage.content, 'html.parser') 
       courselist = courses.select('p.courseblocktitle')     print(dept_courses) 
       for c in courselist: 
            string = c.text 
            data = string.split(".")          
            thewriter.writerow([data[0],data[1]])
```

You should be passing a list to `thewriter`, not a string.