# Python, repl.it - details are not being written to file using csv.writer and writer.writerow

Tags: python, csv, file-writing

I have the following repl.it program, and note that the registration part of the program, that was working fine before, has stopped working.

It gets to the end where it says "written to file" but somehow the actual write-rows command is being skipped as nothing is written to the text file.

**The whole program is here:**

https://repl.it/@oiuwdeoiuas/Matchmakingskills-1

**The relevant part of the code is below,** although there may be other factors (hence whole code provided)

```
def register():
    print("===Register====")
    print("First things first, sign up and tell us a little about yourself")
    with open("dating.txt","a") as fo: 
        writer=csv.writer(fo)        
        firstname=input("Enter first name:")
        lastname=input("Enter last name:")
        username=firstname+lastname[0]+"bird"
        print("Your automatically generated username is:",username)
        password=input("Enter password:")
        gender=input("Enter gender")
        email=input("Enter email:")
        dob=input("Enter date of birth in format dd/mm/yy:")
        beliefs=input("Enter beliefs")
        strengthslist=["patience","efficiency","sensitivity","frankness","submissiveness","leadership","timekeeping","laidback"]
        print(strengthslist)
        strengths=input("Enter your top strength: (select from the above list)")
        contactcount=0
        writer.writerow([username,password,firstname,lastname,gender,email,dob,beliefs,strengths,contactcount])
        print("written to file")
        mainmenu()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to read a file that's still open:

```python
def register():
    # ...
    with open("dating.txt","a") as fo: 
        # ...
        print("written to file")
        # At this point, "dating.txt" hasn't been written to
        # the next call to open it that occurs here will
        # see the state of the file either partially written, or before
        # the row is written at all
        mainmenu()
```

There are a few solutions.  The quickest is to de-indent `mainmenu()` here one level:

```python
def register():
    # ...
    with open("dating.txt","a") as fo: 
        # ...
        print("written to file")
    # dating.txt has been closed now, it's safe to read it
    mainmenu()
```

When the next method comes along and tries to read the file, it will contain the expected data that way.

Comment: "with open" is meant to be a feature /command that automatically closes the file - or am I wrong?

Comment: Thank you @Anon Coward - fancy looking at this related context question :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66447589/python-and-csv-reader-failing-to-print-all-the-rows-in-a-text-file-that-do-not?noredirect=1#comment117472859_66447589

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but do you need `writerows` instead of `writerow` because `writerows` accepts a list just as yours and `writerow` accepts columns.

[Like in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285154/csv-writer-writerows-splitting-my-string-inputs)

Comment: [Quoting the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34285238/1431750) from the post you linked: "You are using `writer.writerows()` with an `s` at the end. That method expects a *list of lists*". They both accept lists. `writer.writerow()` expects a list of strings, while `writer.writerows()` expects a list of lists of strings.