# Python and csv reader: Failing to print all the rows in a text file that do NOT have a field that contains a certain string

Tags: python, list, csv

I have the following repl.it program, and cannot get one part of the program to work (the logic is wrong)

The context is that of a dating site. in the "matchmagic" subroutine, I want to be able to retrieve all rows in the database that do NOT have the keystrength variable.

In other words, if a user types in "patience", then every row in the text file that DOES NOT contain that word, is displayed (i.e all the users that are not patient) as we are going for contrasting personalities for a match.

**The whole program is here:**

https://repl.it/@oiuwdeoiuas/Matchmakingskills-1

**The relevant part of the program is:**

```
def matchmagic():
    wordfound=False
    print("===Creating Match===")
    while wordfound==False: 
        with open("dating.txt","r") as f:
            keystrength=input("Enter one of your key strengths:")
            reader=csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                for field in row:
                    if field != keystrength:
                        print(row)
                        wordfound=True
                                   
    search()
                
mainmenu()
```

What I have tried here is obvious, but I think there is an issue with the following:

```
                   if field != keystrength:
                            print(row)
                            wordfound=True
```

It prints all the rows instead of identifying the rows that do not contain that identified keystrength.

**Sample CSV:**

```
Joe,Bloggs,JoeBbird,open123,M,jblogs@gmail.com,10/10/20,Christian,patience,0
```

FName,LName,Username,password,Gender,email,dob,Religion,**keystrength**,contactcount

In the example above, if this user is logged in, their keystrength is "patience", and the program should return all the rows (usernames or first and last names) of users that do NOT have "patience" listed anywhere in their files.

Comment: A related question (to this code) is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66447527/python-repl-it-details-are-not-being-written-to-file-using-csv-writer-and-wri (the registration aspect is failing to work) - registration function is not writing to the file

Comment: Can you post a small example CSV file and a keystrength that generates the error? You are checking all of the columns in each row for the keystrength when you should be checking only the column(s) that actually contain keystrengths. Let us know what the columns are and we can make suggestions from there.

Comment: @tdelaney - I will update the question with this: Joe,Bloggs,JoeBbird,open123,M,jblogs@gmail.com,10/10/20,Christian,patience,0 (the csv file would be generated from the registration function as shown in the whole code)

Comment: Updated question

Comment: @tdelaney - the fact that the registration part of the program has stopped working is another question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66447527/python-repl-it-details-are-not-being-written-to-file-using-csv-writer-and-wri   (doing this for beginners learning python)

Comment: I'm confused about the requirement _users that do NOT have "patience" listed anywhere in their files_. First, its rows of a single CSV file. Second, suppose the user is named Patience or has Usename patience, but whose keystrength is not patience. Should that user be returned? It seems to me that you should only check the keystrength column

Comment: You certainly don't want to look through ALL the fields.  `for row in reader:` / `if row['keystrength'] != keystrength:` `print(row)`.

Comment: @tdelaney - not worrying right now about whether the name is patience - teaching skills (not perfect functionality of the solution atm).

Comment: @TimRoberts - could you post your suggested solution so I can verify please?

Comment: @tdelaney - could you post a solution which does what you suggest (only using the keystrength column )

Comment: I have it working now -feel free to post solutions so I can accept. If no one does in a day or two,I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a header line to the CSV file when it is first created, you can use `csv.DictReader` to read the rows and use the column name to filter. This is nice because both your CSV and your code self document. So, just testing one column, your code could be:

```
import csv

def matchmagic():
    print("===Creating Match===")
    keystrength=input("Enter one of your key strengths:").upper()
    with open("dating.txt","r") as f:
        reader=csv.DictReader(f)
        return [row for row in reader if row["keystrength"].upper()!=keystrength]

result = matchmagic()
for r in result:
    print(r.values())
```

dating.txt

```
FName,LName,Username,password,Gender,email,dob,Religion,keystrength,contactcount
Joe,Bloggs,JoeBbird,open123,M,jblogs@gmail.com,10/10/20,Christian,patience,0
Darth,Vader,vader6599,open123,M,dvader@deathstar.com,10/10/20,Sith,impatience,0
```

This code is testing for exact matches. I added "impatience" to highlight that a test of whether "patience" is just somewhere in the string can be problematic.