# Writer (cvs) is treating each character as a field

Tags: python, csv, writer

Writer is writing a list to a csv file but treating each character as a field:

```
nteams =16
c = 1
teams = []

while c <= nteams:
    teams.append("Team " + str(c))
    c = c + 1
```

This bit creates the list properly and returns the following `teams`:

```py
['Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3', 'Team 4']
```

Then I do this:

```
import csv

# writing the data into the file
with open ('teams.csv','w') as f:
    wtr = csv.writer(f)
    wtr.writerows(teams)
```

But this bit returns this to the csv file:

```
T,e,a,m, ,1
T,e,a,m, ,2
T,e,a,m, ,3
T,e,a,m, ,4
```

This is not good. Help please.

I've tried changing the open mode "WB" and "W":

```py
with open ('teams.csv','w') as f:
                        ^
```

Comment: This has been explicitly answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285154/csv-writer-writerows-splitting-my-string-inputs

Answer (score 0):

The `writerows` method expects a list of lists. You are passing it a list of strings. You can use a list comprehension to create a list of lists:

```py
import csv

nteams =16
c = 1
teams = []

while c <= nteams:
    teams.append("Team " + str(c))
    c = c + 1

with open ('teams.csv','w') as f:
    wtr = csv.writer(f)
    wtr.writerows([[team] for team in teams])
```

Output:

```
Team 1
Team 2
Team 3
Team 4
```

Comment: That is outstanding.  One thing; I get blank record in-between when i open the csv in Excel...

Comment: Interesting in between which two? Also if you print out `teams` after your list is created what do you see?

Comment: @MarkLewis, it looks like this answer solves your problem. If so, please accept it by clicking the checkmark near the top of the answer. Thank you :)

Comment: My last comment is answered by the related link 672.  Added  'newline=' parameter in the Open method.